# HLK test failing (HyperVisor Code Integrity Readiness Test)

Tags: driver, wdk

I have installed the 1903 HLK client on a fresh 64bit Windows 10 1903 machine but I am always getting a failure for the HyperVisor Code Integrity Readiness Test.

Previously it was successful when using HLK 1809.

Even if I test beep.sys it fails, and at different stages each time.
In the client event log I found this:

> There was an Unhandled exception in the handler. Exception:
>   System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   path1    at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.Diagnostics.ExecutionAgentPlugin.LogHelper.BuildCopyFileInfosForDirectory(String
>   directoryPath, DiagnosticLogType logType)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.Diagnostics.ExecutionAgentPlugin.LogHelper.BuildCopyFileInfosForDirectory(DiagnosticLogInfo
>   logInfo)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.Diagnostics.ExecutionAgentPlugin.BitsJobHandler.Upload(String
>   jobNamePrefix, LogHelper logHelper, Boolean createManifest)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.Diagnostics.ExecutionAgentPlugin.JobEndHandler.Start()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.Diagnostics.ExecutionAgentPlugin.Program.InitializeHandler(Options
>   options)    at
>   Microsoft.Windows.Kits.Hardware.Diagnostics.ExecutionAgentPlugin.Program.Main(String[]
>   args)

The WTT log file seems to indicate success.

Comment: Have you had resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I personally had to install [Windows Hardware Lab Kit Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/test/hlk/user/windows-hardware-lab-kit-filters) in order to pass failing tests (error message was the same). From MSDN:

> When Microsoft discovers a problem in either a Windows HLK test or in the operating system itself that causes certification tests to fail incorrectly, we create an errata that allows partners to pass the problematic test. Many errata use filters to automatically filter the failure from the submission results.  Filters are applied within Windows HLK Studio.